# How to show only 1 tab at page load

Tags: javascript, php

I have my page built up like a navigation bar and below that i have in-page tabs, which are showing different content, but i can't get it to show only one of them at load.

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified tab-links">
                    <li class="active"><a id="tab1" class="pillsnavigation" href="#tab1">Adressbuch</a></li>
                    <li><a class="pillsnavigation" href="#tab2">Neuer Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and now i want the page to show "tab1" when it's loading the first time, how do i do that?

my JS:

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function (e) {
                var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

                // Show/Hide Tabs

                jQuery('.tab' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

                // Change/remove current tab to active
                jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

                e.preventDefault();
            });`enter code here`
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you also post the code for the tab contents?

Comment: So hide it with CSS to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tab-pane").removeClass('active');
    $("#tab1").addClass('active');
});
```

If you tab HTML is like this

```
<div class="tabs-container">
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane">
        <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInDown">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="previewTemplate" class="tab-pane">
        <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInDown">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sadly this doesn't work, the othe tab won't hide it is still below the other

Comment: Okay, I think i fiured out the problem it's that the whole thing is in 1 HTML file which causes it to load the complete thing at start, but how do I prevent that? so it whould only load the <div> element i want?

Comment: @TheYaINN try now.

Comment: this works, but how do i now change the "active" im really sorry bothering you but im still learning only programming for 2 weeks.
NVM. I figured it out! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Show/Hide Tabs
    var parentLi = $(this).parent();
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links li').not(parentLi).hide();

    // Change/remove current tab to active 
    //jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified tab-links">
          <li class="active"><a id="tab1" class="pillsnavigation" href="#tab1">Adressbuch</a></li>
          <li><a class="pillsnavigation" href="#tab2">Neuer Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I've figured it out! :)